How to link to embedded SharePoint Video similar to youtube
How can I make the "Jump to 1:30" text link jump to the embedded SharePoint video above and start autoplay at 1:30, without modifying the default start time of the embedded video? Youtube has this feature where user can post comments and link to the video above that starts at a specific time. Is it possible with SharePoint?
Here is my code
<iframe id="videoEmbed" src="abc.sharepoint.com/sites/"></iframe>

<script>   document.getElementById('jumpLink').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior

    const videoIframe = document.getElementById('videoEmbed');
    const startTime = 90; // 1:30 in seconds

    // Send the seek command to the iframe via postMessage
    videoIframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
      event: "command",
      func: "seek",
      args: [startTime]
    }), "*");   }); </script>

